# What could be wrong with my integrated graphic card?

Tags: graphics-card

Today when i removed my AGP card to clean it's fan and tried to start my PC with using integrated card, before PC could boot the picture froze and became distorted. After that I hit the restart button and then it booted normaly. Could it be that it's due to the fact that I didn't change BIOS settings to allow my integrated card to be used or is it that my integrated card is dying?

This is the picture of what showed up on my screen:

[image]

### My PC configuration:

**Computer Brand Name**: FUJITSU SIEMENS SCENIC N / SCENICO N
**Operating System**: Microsoft Windows XP Professional Build 2600
**Service Pack**: Service Pack 3
**Processor**: Intel Pentium 4-2400 (2400.0 MHz)
**Motherboard**: FUJITSU SIEMENS D1561 (Intel 865G (Springdale-G) + ICH5)
**Memory**: 640 MBytes (Single-Channel)
**Hard Drive**: Maxtor 6E040L0 (39,204 MBytes (41 GB))
**Optical Drive**: SONY CD-RW CRX216E (CD-R Writer)
**Display Adapter**: GIGABYTE GV-N55128D(P)
**Audio Adapter**: Intel 82801EB(M) ICH5(-M) - AC'97 Audio Controller [A-2/A-3]
**Network Adapter**: Intel 82547EI Gigabit Ethernet Controller (LOM)
TP-LINK 150Mbps Wireless Lite N Adapter
**Monitor**: LG W1941

Comment: Did you supply a driver and remove the unused display drivers?

Comment: Are you sure you don't just have a really cool boot screen? :P

Comment: No I didn't remove the unused display drivers, nor did I install the ones for the integrated card. Could that be an issue?

Comment: Hahaha, good one Moses :D

Comment: @StevanJovanovic - The image provider you used wasn't accessible, I took a wild guess, after looking at what happens its clear this is a defective hardware problem .

Comment: @Ramhound I uploaded his image to the post.

Comment: @Moses - Understood hence my updated response.